# In C++, can you construct child member first, to be used in a parent constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, parent-child

Here's a simplified version of the base class, I didn't write it, and I can't change it:

```
class BufferManager {
public:
    BufferManager(char *buf, size_t size);  
};
```

I'd like to make a class that provides all of the buffer manager's features, along with the buffer itself:

```
class Buffer : public BufferManager {
private:
    std::vector<char> d_buf;
public:
    Buffer(size_t size) : 
        d_buf(size),        // error : reorder!
        BufferManager(&d_buf[0], d_buf.size()) {
    }
}
```

The only way I can think to do this to have a BufferManager member, and then override all of BufferManager's functions (over 40) in my new class.

Is there some way to tell C++ to construct a specific child member first... because it's used in a parent's constructor? Or some templatey way of getting around this?

Comment: Looks dangerous: Passing mutable data and size of a vector to the base class (If these are invariant use an good old array with new or a std::array member and get rid  of d_buf)

Answer (score 4):

No.

But there is a solution — use **one more** base to beat the existing base, at the *who-borns-first* competition.

```
class BufferBase
{
  protected:
     std::vector<char> d_buf;

     BufferBase(std::size_t size)  : d_buf(size) {}
}

class Buffer : private BufferBase, public BufferManager {
private:      

public:
    Buffer(size_t size) 
      : BufferBase(size),
        BufferManager(d_buf.data(), d_buf.size()) {
    }
}
```

Note that `Buffer` **must first** derive from `BufferBase`, then from `BufferManager`. That order guarantees that `BufferBase` will be created first among all. Order of creation:

```
BufferBase => BufferManager => Buffer
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But do note that if `BufferManager` wasn't designed to be inherited (I'm looking at you, non-virtual destructor) this design will get you in a bunch of obscure problems in the future. public inheritance should be used to model substitution which this doesn't appear to be. You would use protected or private inheritance for "implemented-in-terms-of".

Comment: @MarkB: I've always heard that argument and that makes sense. However, I see the standard library uses inheritance a lot, without having virtual destructor in the base (see the implementation of any container). I think it just depends on the documentation which tells the user what not to derive from.

Comment: @Nawaz Which standard container uses public inheritance with a non-virtual destructor? I only checked vector but it used protected inheritance to the implementation base which seems fine.